# Javascript: String with hex to decimal

Tags: javascript, string, hex

I've got this string containing multiple hexadecimal numbers:

`let input = '\x01\x01\x02\x01';`

I would like to see this transformed into: `1121` (the decimal representation of each hex number)

How would I go about this? I've tried numerous things, but the only output I get are some diamond shapes with a questionmark inside of it or syntax errors. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem might be that when you actually use this line in your code

`let input = '\x01\x01\x02\x01';`

The hex values are converted to charcters before running the script. If you would like to have a string with the hex represantation in it you would have to escape the backslashes first: `let input = '\\x01\\x01\\x02\\x01';`

Comment: Your string does not contain hexadecimal numbers but four characters with ASCII codes 1, 1, 2, and 1. Is your question how to convert such a string to '1121', or do you have a misconception about the input string? Does it really look like that assignment? Or does it look like that when you *print* it? There is a huge difference between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple method that escapes the string, removes empty elements, converts each number to is decimal digit, joins it as a string, and then converts the final result to a number.

```js
function convert(string) {
  string = escape(string);
  string = string.split(/%/).filter(e=>e);
  string = string.map(e => +("0x"+e)); 
  return +string.join("");
}

// Test case
var decimal = convert('\x01\x01\x02\x01');
console.log(decimal);
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to work with the escape sequences itself and not the resulting whitespace, you habe to use `String
raw` then you can replace:

```
let input = String.raw`\x01\x01\x02\x01`;

console.log(
  input
   .replace(/\\x01/g, "1")
   .replace(/\\x02/g, "2")
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. In my case Asleespace's answer suits me better, but I could definitely use your String.raw for different purposes in the future.